# Extend JSON files with Python

Tags: python, json, file, merge

I looked my problem up on stackoverflow and there are several solutions to my problem which just don't work in my case.
I  want to add a few new entries to my json file.

My json file (data.json):

```
{
        "blabla1":"dubdub1",
        "blabla2":"dubdub2"
}
```

My code (using the **extend** method):

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)
result = list()

result.extend(data)
result.extend({'blabla3': 'dubdub3'})
data = result

print(data)
```

Which gives me an output like:

```
['blabla1', 'blabla2', 'blabla3']
```

My code (using the **append** method):

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)
result = list()

result.append(data)
result.append({'blabla3': 'dubdub3'})
data = result

print(data)
```

Which gives me an output like:

```
[{'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2'}, {'blabla3': 'dubdub3'}]
```

What I need in the end is this:

```
[{'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2', 'blabla3': 'dubdub3'}]
```

So where am I going wrong? I'm sorry if the same question has already been answered, but I couldn't find something that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want a list with only 1 element? Do you actually want just a dictionary updated with the new keys/values?

Comment: That was one solution I found which didn't work for me. I'm not really experienced with using python or json files.
I just want to add new entries to the dictionary and then later on overwrite the json file (but I think overwriting the file afterwards should be possible without help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this closer to what you want? A dictionary updated with the new key and value

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)
data['blabla3'] = 'dubdub3'
print(data)  # {'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2', 'blabla3': 'dubdub3'}
```

EDIT:

To update multiple entries at the same time you can use `update`

```
data.update({
    'blabla3': 'dubdub3',
    'blabla4': 'dubdub4',
})
```

Comment: So in the case I would like to add more entries simultaneously I would use a for each loop to iterate over my keys in the dictionary I want to add?

Comment: To add entries in 1 call you can use `update`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Without changing your code much you could achieve your original request like this:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)

data.update({'blabla3': 'dubdub3'})
result = [data]

print(result)
```

Which will produce your expected result:

```
[{'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2', 'blabla3': 'dubdub3'}]
```

### Short explanation:

The method *json.load* you called created a dictionary object *data* that looks like this:

```
{'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2'}
```

Then by calling *result.append(data)* you added the *data* dictionary as the first citizen in the list object *result*:

```
[{'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2'}]
```

And every other time you call the *append()* method you will just add another member to the list:

```
[{'blabla1': 'dubdub1', 'blabla2': 'dubdub2'}, obj2, obj3, ...]
```

Instead it seems you wanted to add another key-value pair to the data dictionary as explained in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515832/6284449)